# Как обновить данные в компоненте angular 1.5

Tags: angularjs, компоненты

Есть такой запрос при ините компонента делаю асинхронный запрос

```
class PageCtrl {

    constructor (Page) {
       this.data = {};
       this.Page = Page;
    } 
     $onInit() {
         let _self = this;
         this.Page.get({pid: 23})
            .$promise.then(function (data) {
            _self.data = data;
        });
     }
 }

 export default Angular.module('app.page', [])
               .component('page', {
                  controller:PageCtrl,
                  template:require('./page.html')
                }).name;

 HTML: // page.html

<p>{{$ctrl.data.title}}</p>
// ничего не выводит
```

В итоге данные получил но они не обновляются на вьюхе...

Comment: что за _Page.get_?

Comment: @Grundy поправил, это сервис с $resource

Comment: $promise уберите, Вам уже приходит сразу промис, нужно вызвать только then.

Comment: @MrFylypenko, не в случае `$resource`

Comment: @MrFylypenko нет, именно так работают промисы в $resource

Comment: @Grundy, да, точно, ошибся. А если сделать тестовое поле, оно выводится?

Comment: приведенный [код работает как ожидается](http://plnkr.co/edit/8HZlKSkP29UfuHPZic1d?p=preview), проблема где-то еще. есть ли ошибки в консоли браузера?

Comment: @Grundy https://jsbin.com/bohasu/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: плохой пример, setTimeout не запускает digest цикл после вызова колбэка, при использовании же $http, или $resource, который внутри использует $http - он запускается автоматически после получения данных

Comment: к тому же _this_ внутри setTimeout будет не контроллер

Comment: вот [исправленный пример](https://jsbin.com/necusamogu/1/edit?html,js,console,output)